# App Engine Several Databases For Databastore

Tags: android, sql, google-app-engine

I am thinking about using Google App Engine.

For my project I will need several data stored in different databases. From what I've been reading so far AppEngine only provides one database to store and track users.

My problem is I need to have multiple databases to store the same data but store only the data related to its criteria.

Is AppEngine the way to go for this? Its a android app I will be using by the way.
Or should I have my own server? If so what would I need to implement?

Comment: I guess the question is can App Engine Support multiple tables for data to be stored in

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain, why you need more than one database.
You can use namespaces to create a multitenancy environment. 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy

Comment: Well i guess i wouldnt need mutliple databases. I would just need seperate tables to staore the same columns but just seperate data from other databases

Answer (score 1):

Each entity you define (see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities) is conceptually like a table -- the entity's fields are the equivalent of columns in a table.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.. So could you explain how it works as far as adding new fields to a entitiy. for example i have a entity names "Miami" The "Miami" entitiy has two fields location and name. How do i keep adding new entries to this entity? This is the part i didnt understand.

Comment: No, that's not true at all. Each entity is more like a row than a table.

Comment: Nick is correct. I meant an entity definition is like a table definition. An entity instance is like a row in a table.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the documentation in the link @Moishe supplied in his answer, i figured out the answer.

I just thought i would post an answer here to save someone some time in the future.

Here is a class called employees that accepts App engines Datastore parameters.

```
//Class name Employee
class Employee(db.Model):

//Employee information we want to enter into the Employee entity.
first_name = db.StringProperty()
last_name = db.StringProperty()
hire_date = db.DateProperty()
attended_hr_training = db.BooleanProperty()

//Set employees information to the Database Model to be inserted into the Datastore.
employee = Employee(first_name='Antonio',
                last_name='Salieri')

employee.hire_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
employee.attended_hr_training = True

//Like committ..this initiates the insertion of the information you put into the database store mode. This works sorta like androids bundle or SharedPreference you put the information into the datastore and then committ it or save it. 

employee.put()
```

Comment: whatch out with the comments. in python its `#` not `//`. this code would nor work like this.